# Target Previous Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to target the previous input field of a form element that is in an accordion. I have tried several ways to target the `.image-url` field but I am having trouble with targeting just this one field within the accordion. This may be a simple task but I cannot get this thing to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<form>
    <input class="image-url" type="text" />
    <input class="button" type="button" />
</form>
```

JS

```
$('form .button').click(function() {

    // do stuff
   uploader.on('select', function() {
       $(this).prev().val('text to put');
   }
}
```

This is what I have right now and I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` within the `uploader.on` callback probably isn't the button. Remember the button and then use it in the callback:

```
$('form .button').click(function() {
   var btn = $(this);

    // do stuff
   uploader.on('select', function() {
       btn.prev().val('text to put');
   }
});
```

---

Side note: Whenever I see an event handler hooked up from within another event handler, it raises a flag for me. If the button is clicked twice, you'll end up with two handlers on `uploader` for the `select` event. You might want to check whether that's really what you want...

Side note 2: CSS selectors can do more than just `id`s and classes, you may not need that `class="button"` on the button. You can select it via `form input[type=button]` (in your CSS for styling, and in a jQuery `$()` call and similar to locate it).